# How to enable multiple disabled buttons via checkboxes (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Explanation:
On our website, we have one button that leads to third-party surveys. In order to comply with the GDPR, we want the user to 1. accept the cookies via our cookie consent system before they are able to click on the buttons. For this reason, the buttons are disabled by default. There's a hint text saying you need to accept the cookies first, and this text is only shown if the cookies haven't been accepted yet.
Upon acceptance of the cookies, that text hint is hidden, and a checkbox appears (the checkbox was hidden and is shown only upon acceptance of the cookies). The user lastly needs to check the box in order for the button to be enabled.

This has been working fine so far with just one button on a page. However, we now want to have several buttons of this kind on a single page complete with a checkbox and hint text each, and unfortunately, this implementation seems to only work on the first button on the page, but not the others. By that I mean: the first button together with its checkbox and hint text work as intended, but the other hint texts are not shown/hidden depending on the cookie acceptance, and the checkboxes only disable/enable the very first button.

The html (checkbox, button to the survey, hint text:

```
<div id="consent-surverymonkey-given" style="display:none" class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" id="accept-surveymonkey" name='surveymonkey' autocomplete="off" />
  <label id="button-accepted" for="accept-surveymonkey" class="checkbox-text">
  Nach Anklicken dieser Checkbox und durch Interaktion auf den Button "Angebot anfordern" erklären Sie sich mit unseren <a href="/meta/datenschutz.html" class="text-link-black">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> einverstanden.
  </label>
</div>

<a style="border-radius:40px;" href="/kontakt/blockchain-consulting-angebotsanfrage" target="_self">
<input style="border:none !important;" disabled type="submit" name="consentSurveymonkey" class="button width" id="consentSurveymonkey" value="Angebot anfordern" /></a>

<p id="consent-surverymonkey-denied" style="margin:0;padding:0;">Um das Formular nutzen zu können, müssen Sie zuvor unsere Marketing-Cookies bestätigen.<br>Die Cookie-Schaltzentrale finden Sie 
   <a class="text-link-black" href="#" onclick="UC_UI.showSecondLayer();">
   hier</a>.</p>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
function switchConsentSurveymonkey() {
var isChecked = document.getElementById('accept-surveymonkey').checked;
document.getElementById('consentSurveymonkey').disabled = !isChecked;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", switchConsentSurveymonkey);
document.getElementById('accept-surveymonkey').addEventListener("change", switchConsentSurveymonkey);
</script>

<script type="text/plain" data-usercentrics="SurveyMonkey">
        document.getElementById('consent-surverymonkey-denied').style="display:none";
        document.getElementById('consent-surverymonkey-given').style="display:block";
</script>
```

The script was not made by me but by our developer, who cannot be reached. I'm actually just a designer, and I don't really know much about javascript. But it looks like the script is only targeting IDs, and since we now have multiple buttons to target, we should probably use a class instead. I tried to switch out the parts "getElementById" with "getElementsByClassName" in the script, and assigned "accept-surveymonkey", "consentSurveymonkey", "consent-surverymonkey-given" and "consent-surverymonkey-denied" as classes to the respective elements instead of as IDs, like so:

```
<script>
    function switchConsentSurveymonkey() {
    var isChecked = document.getElementsByClassName('.accept-surveymonkey').checked;
    document.getElementsByClassName('.consentSurveymonkey').disabled = !isChecked;
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", switchConsentSurveymonkey);
    document.getElementsByClassName('.accept-surveymonkey').addEventListener("change", switchConsentSurveymonkey);
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/plain" data-usercentrics="SurveyMonkey">
            document.getElementsByClassName('.consent-surverymonkey-denied').style="display:none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('.consent-surverymonkey-given').style="display:block";
    </script>


<div style="display:none" class="form-group consent-surverymonkey-given">
      <input type="checkbox" class="accept-surveymonkey" id="surveymonkey-checkbox" name='surveymonkey' autocomplete="off" />
      <label for="surveymonkey-checkbox" class="checkbox-text button-accepted">
      Nach Anklicken dieser Checkbox und durch Interaktion auf den Button "Angebot anfordern" erklären Sie sich mit unseren <a href="/meta/datenschutz.html" class="text-link-black">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> einverstanden.
      </label>
    </div>

    <a style="border-radius:40px;" href="/kontakt/blockchain-consulting-angebotsanfrage" target="_self">
    <input style="border:none !important;" disabled type="submit" name="consentSurveymonkey" class="button consentSurveymonkey" value="Angebot anfordern" /></a>

    <p class="consent-surverymonkey-denied" style="margin:0;padding:0;">Um das Formular nutzen zu können, müssen Sie zuvor unsere Marketing-Cookies bestätigen.<br>Die Cookie-Schaltzentrale finden Sie 
       <a class="text-link-black" href="#" onclick="UC_UI.showSecondLayer();">
       hier</a>.</p>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Probably not, considering I get the console error "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function". Another thought of mine is to give each button+checkbox their own IDs separate from the other buttons+checkboxes, and make duplicate scripts for each button+checkbox, but I assume this would be a pretty bad practice (if it would work)? I'm not sure what else to do, so I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for the example with classes, and if you keep the same HTML layout of the elements:

```js
/*
        hardcoded for this structure:

        div
            checkbox
        ahref
            button
        p
            ahref
     */
function switchConsentSurveymonkey(ev) {
  ev.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.disabled = !ev.target.checked;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.consent-surverymonkey-given')).forEach(cbx => {
    cbx.querySelector('input').addEventListener("change", switchConsentSurveymonkey);
  });


  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.consent-surverymonkey-denied .text-link-black')).forEach(e => {

    e.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.style = 'display:block';
      ev.target.parentElement.style = 'display:none';

    });

  })

});
```

```html
<div style="display:none" class="form-group consent-surverymonkey-given">
  <input type="checkbox" class="accept-surveymonkey" id="surveymonkey-checkbox" name='surveymonkey' autocomplete="off" />
  <label for="surveymonkey-checkbox" class="checkbox-text button-accepted">
      Nach Anklicken dieser Checkbox und durch Interaktion auf den Button "Angebot anfordern" erklären Sie sich mit unseren <a href="/meta/datenschutz.html" class="text-link-black">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> einverstanden.
      </label>
</div>

<a style="border-radius:40px;" href="/kontakt/blockchain-consulting-angebotsanfrage" target="_self">
  <input style="border:none !important;" disabled type="submit" name="consentSurveymonkey" class="button consentSurveymonkey" value="Angebot anfordern" /></a>

<p class="consent-surverymonkey-denied" style="margin:0;padding:0;">Um das Formular nutzen zu können, müssen Sie zuvor unsere Marketing-Cookies bestätigen.<br>Die Cookie-Schaltzentrale finden Sie
  <a class="text-link-black" href="#">
       hier</a>.</p>



<div style="display:none" class="form-group consent-surverymonkey-given">
  <input type="checkbox" class="accept-surveymonkey" id="surveymonkey-checkbox" name='surveymonkey' autocomplete="off" />
  <label for="surveymonkey-checkbox" class="checkbox-text button-accepted">
      Nach Anklicken dieser Checkbox und durch Interaktion auf den Button "Angebot anfordern" erklären Sie sich mit unseren <a href="/meta/datenschutz.html" class="text-link-black">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> einverstanden.
      </label>
</div>

<a style="border-radius:40px;" href="/kontakt/blockchain-consulting-angebotsanfrage" target="_self">
  <input style="border:none !important;" disabled type="submit" name="consentSurveymonkey" class="button consentSurveymonkey" value="Angebot anfordern" /></a>

<p class="consent-surverymonkey-denied" style="margin:0;padding:0;">Um das Formular nutzen zu können, müssen Sie zuvor unsere Marketing-Cookies bestätigen.<br>Die Cookie-Schaltzentrale finden Sie
  <a class="text-link-black" href="#">
       hier</a>.</p>



<div style="display:none" class="form-group consent-surverymonkey-given">
  <input type="checkbox" class="accept-surveymonkey" id="surveymonkey-checkbox" name='surveymonkey' autocomplete="off" />
  <label for="surveymonkey-checkbox" class="checkbox-text button-accepted">
      Nach Anklicken dieser Checkbox und durch Interaktion auf den Button "Angebot anfordern" erklären Sie sich mit unseren <a href="/meta/datenschutz.html" class="text-link-black">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> einverstanden.
      </label>
</div>

<a style="border-radius:40px;" href="/kontakt/blockchain-consulting-angebotsanfrage" target="_self">
  <input style="border:none !important;" disabled type="submit" name="consentSurveymonkey" class="button consentSurveymonkey" value="Angebot anfordern" /></a>

<p class="consent-surverymonkey-denied" style="margin:0;padding:0;">Um das Formular nutzen zu können, müssen Sie zuvor unsere Marketing-Cookies bestätigen.<br>Die Cookie-Schaltzentrale finden Sie
  <a class="text-link-black" href="#">
       hier</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer! The checkboxes and the enabling/disabling of the buttons works nicely. However, the switch for hiding the checkbox and showing the cookie hint text (& vice versa) depending on the cookie acceptance is not working. The result is that the checkbox is shown and the cookie hint is text hidden by default, and nothing changes if I accept or decline the cookies. Could you help me out once more?

Comment: check updated code. However, you seem to be using some third party consent solution, so probably all the new choices will have to be first configured, and then passed to it..